# Django DRF and generic relations: how to obtain content_object field from API response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, generic-relations

I have implemented Generic Relations in Django DRF following the official guide and it works well, apart from the fact that I cannot seem to obtain the field content_object from my API response.

Basically, I have a model called Document that can either be related to a model called Folder or a model called Collection.

```
class Document(models.Model):

    limit = models.Q(app_label='folders', model='folder') | models.Q(
        app_label='collections', model='collection')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # Field necessari per la Generic Relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to=limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type', 'object_id')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Folder(models.Model):
    ...
    documents = GenericRelation(Document)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Collection(models.Model):
    ...
    documents = GenericRelation(Document)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class ContentObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        if isinstance(value, Folder):
            serializer = FolderSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, Collection):
            serializer = CollectionSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of object')

        return serializer.data


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content_type',
                  'object_id', 'category')


class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documents = DocumentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ("id", "title", "description",
                  "documents")
        depth = 1

(Collection serializer is essentially the same ad the Folder serializer, with its own fields).
```

I was expecting to be able to access the content of the field content_object when retrieving - with a GET request to the API endpoint - the documents.
Instead, that field is not available. If I do try to add it to the fields listed in its serializers, it throws an error.

How can I access that content so that I know, for each document, to what folder or what collection is belongs exactly?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ContentObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Folder):
            serializer = FolderForDocumentSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, Collection):
            serializer = CollectionForDocumentSerializer(value) # Defines CollectionForDocumentSerializer in the same manner of FolderForDocumentSerializer
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of object')

        return serializer.data


class FolderForDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ("id", "title", "description")
        depth = 1


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_object = ContentObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content_object', 'category')

# Note that you can use DocumentSerializer and CollectionSerializer, but not in ContentObjectRelatedField.to_representation
```

Your frontend can deduct the type of content_object inspecting the returned fields

Comment: Hello, thank you, but it doesn't work. It crashes the server.

Comment: @Giulia can you provide the details of the error?

Comment: Sure, here is it: Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Python runtime state: initialized

Comment: @Giulia The problem is that FolderSerializer / CollectionSerializer refers to DocumentSerializer and DocumentSerializer refers to FolderSerializer / CollectionSerializer, there is a recursive problem. You need to create separate serializers for Folder and Collection that you only use in ContentObjectRelatedField that have not a documents field (I have updated my answer for details)